Access Private S3 Directory Files Through CloudFront Using AWS Signature
I'm trying to access files stored in a private directory within my S3 bucket through CloudFront. Here's the setup:

S3 Bucket Configuration:

Some files are public and can be accessed by anyone.
Other files are stored in a private directory (e.g., bucket_root/upload) and can only be accessed with the correct AWS credentials.


Authentication Flow:

Users authenticate with their Google account, which allows them to obtain an identity from a Cognito Identity Pool.
This identity grants them a temporary IAM role that includes a permission policy allowing access to the private upload folder in the S3 bucket.
Using these credentials, I'm able to access the private files via Postman by sending a request to the S3 REST endpoint using a URL like https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/upload/index.html (this is from my understanding REST virtual hosted style url for requesting objects in the bucket). I use the AWS Signature authorization method in Postman, providing the AccessKey, SecretKey, AWS Region, Service Name (s3), and SessionToken (necessary for temporary security credentials).


Desired Behavior:

I want to access the same private files through a CloudFront distribution URL (e.g., https://cloudfront_distribution/upload/index.html) by sending the same security credentials as headers.

Current Issue:

When I change the URL in Postman to the CloudFront distribution URL and use the same AWS Signature parameters, I receive a 404 Not Found error.

I've already added both a CachingDisabled cache policy and an origin request policy that forwards all headers, cookies, and query strings, but the problem persists.


What am I missing in this setup, and how can I correctly configure CloudFront to serve the private S3 files using AWS Signature for authentication?

I configured my CloudFront distribution to forward all headers, cookies, and query strings to the S3 origin using an origin request policy.

I also disabled caching with a custom cache policy.

I attempted to access a private file in the S3 upload directory via the CloudFront distribution URL by generating an AWS Signature in Postman, using the AccessKey, SecretKey, SessionToken, AWS Region, and Service Name (s3).

I expected CloudFront to forward the request to the S3 bucket with the provided AWS Signature and return the private file (index.html) stored in the upload directory, just as it does when I access the S3 REST endpoint directly.

Instead of receiving the requested file, I encountered a 404 Not Found error, with CloudFront seemingly not recognizing or correctly processing the request to the S3 origin.



I don't think you can use IAM credentials to authenticate to CloudFront. If you want CloudFront to serve private content, you will need to generate pre-signed URLs. See: Restrict access to files - Amazon CloudFront
